# The red cup(?) in the Millennium Falcon (Lego 7965)

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon, lego, lego-star-wars

Background: The Millennium Falcon kit was a Christmas gift to my son, and we have been working on it several hours a day since Christmas day.  We have finished bags 1 through 5, and tomorrow we will break open bag 6 and complete the model.  If you haven't done one of these before, don't think it's a simple undertaking.

The main deck of the ship has a recognizable prop from each prominent scene in "A New Hope", on the forward port deck one finds the holo chess board where R2 played against Chewie for example.  The aft starboard deck has the hover droid that trained Luke on his light sabre.

The aft port deck features a prop which looks like a red coffee cup.  It's immediately in front of the air circulation units and situated directly on the deck.  It is the only prop in the aft port quadrant of the ship, and conspicuously so; hence my curiosity.

[image: Picture of LEGO cup in question]

What might this prop be referring to?  Or is it related to a scene in another episode?

Comment: Don't we have a Lego SE site? http://bricks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a Lego SE site, but I think the intent of this question is to determine its source in the movies, if any, so I think this is a better site for that.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have to do so much with Lego as how it ties in to the Star Wars films.  And per below, the red cup appears to be an anachronism.

Comment: I think this is funny. My wife and i are building it and I thought the mug was weird and had to look it up on the net and sure enough some one else thought of it too. Why isn't R2D2 in the kit and C3PO.... HUMMMM! Darth Vaders in the kit maybe when he walked onto the falcon he left his coffee cup!

Comment: given its relative size, and the fact that it attaches to the plate, I would expect it's not supposed to be a cup. It's probably supposed to be some kind of furnace or other glowing red hot piece of random equipment.

Comment: I just posted this link over at Lego answers SE chat. Maybe someone over there has more info.

Comment: Short of getting in touch with the LEGO designer who worked on the Millenium Falcon, I doubt bricks.se is going to be able to help in any way.

Comment: Clearly it's a red Solo cup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I read once that LEGO has this sort of agreement with Lucasfilm, where LEGO is required to put a certain amount of details in their Star Wars sets. Beyond that (remembering that this LEGO set is a toy), they are allowed to add some "fun" elements to their sets.

So this red mug is just added for fun. It makes no appearance in the Star Wars movies.

[looking for reference link to confirm]

Comment: This is fine.  I have just skimmed the 6 episodes and am now confident that there are no drinking vessels with a handle anywhere in the series.  This includes the dining scene between Anakin and Padme in the second episode.  Thanks for this confirmation.  Also, if you look at the extreme upper-left of 'Keen's' photo, there's a gray cube.  This holds the wrench that Chewee brandished in anger in "The Empire Strikes Back", further confirming tht the model is multi-episodic.

Comment: My brother's girlfriend's son got a pretty cool truck/boat/trailer Lego set not long ago and it came with the little red coffee mug as well.  The mug is seemingly out of place in a set that's about a truck that can pull a boat with a trailer, so it's probably just a common item that Lego throws in with their sets so the Lego men and women can have items to get their little clasps on. As this answer suggests.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, this is indeed a lego "in-joke". The [red lego mug](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-mug-3899-6264) been used in over 340 sets since the 1980s. This includes the A-Wing Fighter and Ackbar's Cruiser sets.

The cups even made an appearance in the Lego Movie.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed the other day that his helmet is a beer hat.

Comment: @Mazura - Yes. And the tips are made out of the same red cup :-)

Comment: It's in the new "Freemaker Adventures" sets too; http://thenerdrecites.com/review-lego-star-wars-75147-starscavenger-the-freemaker-adventures-2048/